# Azure Website Local Call WebException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, selenium, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to use Phantom and Selenium to make a call to my own website in Azure.

It works locally, but it doesn't when I deploy it to Azure which results in the following exception:

> Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>
> ```
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 
>               An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:49888
>
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
>
> at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
>
> Exception Details: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 127.0.0.1:49888
> ```

([Fuller trace](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7032074/))

I think I might have to add a firewall rule or something but I'm really unsure. The website is an Azure website.

If I can fix this from C# code without touching server configurations - that would be a lot more preferable.

Comment: Is 49888 the actual port your site is available at or is selenium trying to setup some kind of control here? Do you have influence on the use of localhost vs. public hostname?

Comment: @SimonOpelt 49888 is the port selenium uses to connect to a driver from what I understand. Any solution is acceptable I have no sentiment towards port number 49888 :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume I ran into the very same issue, however, in some other scenario, where I needed to make web requests from a background worker thread to the public interface of the website. Locally it worked, but once deployed in Azure, the requests started to throw a `WebException` caused by this `SocketException`.

Although I needed not to process the web response in any way, the solution here was to store the web response on stack and dispose it properly by calling its `Close()` method:

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;

try {
    var webReq = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
    webReq.Method = "GET";
    response = (HttpWebResponse)webReq.GetResponse();
}
finally {
    if (response != null) response.Close();
}
```

The exceptions steadily started with request #249 (first 248 requests threw no exception). I therefore assume some kind of web request or web response pooling is taking place in the background and not calling `Close()` on response objects may exhaust this pool at some point or under specific conditions.

Comment: This can probably be nicer by using `using`. Thanks for the answer but I don't think this is the issue we've had.